# Checkbox's checked parameter issue when sending a form

Tags: php, html

I am using a basic `form` structure to simulate a toggle switch:

```
    <form class="" action="" method="post">

       <input id="hola" type="checkbox"  name="probando" onchange="submit()" checked>
       <label class="switch" for="hola" >
            <span style='position:absolute;'></span>
       </label>
   </form>
```

And to receive the data just with this little code:

```
if (isset($_POST['probando'])) {
      $valor_checkbox = $_POST['probando'];
}
```

The problem is that if I keep the `checked` parameter in the checkbox I receive nothing from the form. Is the first time I face this issue and I can't solve it my-self. I have tried changing the position of the parameter, but nothing happens.

Comment: Where is the form posting to? or is it posting to itself

Comment: @Innervisions is posting to itself.

Comment: Why don't you keep the "checked" parameter in a session? pre-set the session to checked or something and when u submit it change the session might work better for you

Comment: @Innervisions Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: Where is your value of the checkbox?

Comment: @Innervisions I am not using it because is not necessary, but if I use them I face the same problem.

Comment: @JetLagFox It will never work because you chosed to name a function as reserved javascript word. submit() is a reserved javascript word. Look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: I appreciate, but I´m using it in another form and works fine (not using javascript). Why is it working if I remove the `checked` parameter?

Comment: Bro you can't implement a programming bad practice just because you see it works. You must not use javascript reserved words. Sooner or later it will throw you an error

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use `"submit()"` as a function created by you because it's a javascript reserved word. Look at this link for more information: [javascript reserved words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)**

You can use Jquery with ajax to send the value to the same form and charge it to a div. You can check the value of check box there. Here is my working snippet:

```js
function enviar(){

  if($("#probando").is(':checked')){
    $("#probando").val("1"); // is checked
  }else{
      $("#probando").val("0"); // is not checked
    }
      probando=$("#probando").val();
    
  alert(probando);
   
  $('#form, #fat, #test_check').submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'probando':probando},
      success: function(data) {
        $('#recibe_checkbox').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test_check" id="test_check" class="" action="" method="post">

   <input id="probando" name="probando" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="enviar()" checked>
   <label class="switch" for="hola" >
        <span style='position:absolute;'></span>
   </label>
   
   <div id="recibe_checkbox" name="recibe_checkbox">
     <?php 
       if ($_POST['probando']=1) {
         $valor_checkbox = $_POST['probando'];
         echo $valor_checkbox;
       }
     ?>
   </div>
```

Check the ajax because it's an example, you didn't post the name of your file so you have to modify the ajax to the urll or action attribute that suit your needs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @JetLagFox test my answer

Answer (score -1):

Give a value to your checkbox, that exact value will be in your `$_POST` variable:

```
    <form class="" action="" method="post">

   <input id="hola" type="checkbox"  name="probando" value="1" onchange="submit()" checked>
   <label class="switch" for="hola" >
        <span style='position:absolute;'></span>
   </label>
```

That will result in your PHP variable `$valor_checkbox` having a value of 1 if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Tried also your solution but keep having the same issue. The value is not required even though, at least in this case.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are receiving nothing is because unchecked check-boxes are not posted to the backend.

You currently have it checked by default (thats what the **checked** does) and are POSTing when that changes (with **onchange="submit()"**) so when you uncheck it there is no data to be posted.

If you would like a value to be posted when it isn't checked you could use a hidden field with the same name, e.g.:

```
<input id="holaHidden" type="hidden" name="probando" value="no">
<input id="hola" type="checkbox"  name="probando" onchange="submit()" checked>
```

Note, this will only work in PHP because it takes the last value posted for a given name.

Comment: Now what will happen to the value of `probando` if you check or uncheck the checkbox? Nothing, because the value is never overwritten, as the check box has no value...

Comment: By default checkboxes post with a value of `on` if one isn't set. So this will post `no` if it is unchecked or `on` if it is checked.